# Sorting JSON sequence

Tags: java, json, java-me

I am trying to write inner follow by inner2 then inner3. However, right now it is inner2, inner3 then inner1. How can I write JSON object to go according to the sequence i want?

```
public void toJSON(String description, String Name)
{
    JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject inner2= new JSONObject();
    JSONObject inner3= new JSONObject();

    try {   
    outer.put("DATA 1", inner);
    inner.put("description", description);  
    inner.put("filename", imageName);

    outer.put("DATA 2", inner2);    
    inner2.put("model", "modelname");

    outer.put("Datetime", inner3);
    inner3.put("Datetime", "DateTime");

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-a-json-array

Comment: Thanks. But I am unable to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JSONObject JavaDocs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

> A JSONObject is an **unordered**
>   collection of name/value pairs.

This means you can't have custom sorting. If you do need custom sorting, wrap the individual objects in a [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html):

```
public void toJSON(String description, String Name){
    JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject inner2 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject inner3 = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    try{
        array.put(inner);
        inner.put("description", description);
        inner.put("filename", imageName);

        array.put(inner2);
        inner2.put("model", "modelname");

        array.put(inner3);
        inner3.put("Datetime", "DateTime");

        outer.put("values", array);

    } catch(JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```